# Incorrect Syntax created by mysql when it exported this table?

Tags: mysql

So I had a set of tables working on an older version of MySQL, however on this new version the tables it exported give a syntax error.

```
CREATE TABLE `joblistings` (
 `jobid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `client` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `service` tinyint(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `firstline` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `city/town/village` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `county` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `postcode` varchar(9) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `daterequired` date(YYY-MM-DD) NOT NULL,
 `timefrom` time(HH:MM),
 `timeto` time(HH:MM),
  PRIMARY KEY (`jobid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`jobid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '**(YYY-MM-DD) NOT NULL,  `timefrom` time(HH:MM), 
>   `timeto` time(HH:MM),   PRIMARY** ' at line 10

These 3 seem to be the problem, from what I understand, however I am not versed well enough in versions and changes to see a way of fixing this.

```
    `daterequired` date(YYY-MM-DD) NOT NULL,
 `timefrom` time(HH:MM),
 `timeto` time(HH:MM),
```

Any help would be much appreciated, keeping this format is important for my system to function.

Comment: `date and time` will have the default format in the db and hence you do not need to provide the format explicitly `daterequired date() NOT NULL, timefrom time(),....`

Comment: I've edited the question to add the error message, something you should have done yourself.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario thank you, sorry I did not think to add that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the format of the date and time. It will be stored in the default format(`'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'`). You can refer the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-types.html) for more details.

The [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd314) after setting it to default format.

If you want to get the output in some other format then you have to use the   [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to get it in your required format.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.

The version I was working with before used UNIX Timestamp's format, so I had to specify it.